# Turn {4, 9, {8, {5}}, {2, 3}} into {4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}} with Map

Tags: list-manipulation

*That's the input I've put*

```
dagny[x_] := x^2;
  Map[dagny, {4, 9, {8, {5}}, {2, 3}}, {2}]
```

Output:

```
{4, 9, {64, {25}}, {4, 9}}
```

But this not I want.
 I wanna `{4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}}`

**How to Map that at a specific Level?**

Comment: As a 'pure' function, after J.M's comment: `Map[If[AtomQ[#], (#^2&)[#],#] &,exp,{2}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[dagny]
dagny[x : Except[_List]] := x^2;
dagny[x_] := x

Map[dagny, {4, 9, {8, {5}}, {2, 3}}, {2}]
```

> {4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {4, 9, {8, {5}}, {2, 3}};

f[x_] := x^2
```

Using `Replace`

```
Replace[list, {{x_, y_List} :> {f @ x, y}, {x__} :> f /@ {x}}, {1}]
```

{4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplaceAt`:

```
p = Position[list, x_ /; AtomQ[x], {2}, Heads -> False]

(*{{3, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}}*)

ReplaceAt[list, x_ :> x^2, p]

(*{4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}}*)
```

Or using rules and `ReplaceAll`:

```
rules = {{a_Integer, b_List} :> {a^2, b}, {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> {a, b}^2};

list /. rules

(*{4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}}*)
```

Or using `ReplacePart`:

```
f = #^2 &;

ReplacePart[#, Thread[p -> f@Extract[#, p]]] &@list

(*{4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}}*)
```

Or using `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[f@# &, list, p]

(*{4, 9, {64, {5}}, {4, 9}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
MapAt[dagny, {4, 9, {8, {5}}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 1}, {4}}]
```

Comment: Nope. Map at a specific level. You're trying to do with the position in  a list. What I want here is a a level stuff.

Comment: @kile, then you need to modify the function you're mapping: `Map[If[! ListQ[#], #^2, #] &, {4, 9, {8, {5}}, {2, 3}}, {2}]`

Comment: @J.M. For more generality, I recommend `AtomQ`.

Comment: @bcegkmqs23  how to achieve that with ```AtomQ?``` can u write it in the answer?

Comment: @kile, Compare and contrast: `Map[If[AtomQ[#], #^2, #] &, {4, 9, {8, {5}}, {2, 3}}, {2}]`. Alternatively, you could modify the definition of your function to be mapped: `dagny[x_?AtomQ] := x^2; dagny[x_] := x`.